# Data Type Conversion Error on Approval Submission in Flow

Tags: visual-workflow, approval-process, error-messages

I have a flow that runs the following steps:

1. Screen allowing the following user inputs:

   - Total Allowable (Currency)
   - Total Paid (Currency)
   - Has Supporting Documents (Text Dropdown)
   - Reason Code (Text Dropdown)
2. Assignment of those values to a custom SObject (Superbill_Correction__c)

   - I've confirmed that each flow variable type matches the corresponding Superbill_Correction field. The dropdown variables associated fields are unrestricted picklists whose active values match the dropdown options.
3. Fast Create the Superbill_Correction__c
4. Submit the Superbill_Correction__c for approval.

   - This step has a fault screen if it fails

The process errors out on step 4, I think.

The FlowApplication error emails only mention up to step 2 with a successful result. Putting flow debugs on finer shows that the steps 1, 2, and 3 complete successfully. It starts step 4 by finding the specified approval, staging all of the approval stuff, and then errors out.

The logs provide an error id of 1769077608-152280 (1406405942), which I haven't been able to find anything useful about, and says that the error type is handled. This last part makes sense because step 4 has a fault path. However when it errors out it doesn't display the fault screen, it just provides the standard unhandled fault message.

The final error message is:

> Flow encountered an error when processing and converting between data types. Please check the flow and ensure all data types are matched correctly.|FlowScreen|RegularSuperBillScreen

RegularSuperBillScreen is step 1, which the logs said completed no problem. Even weirder is that at one point I inserted a screen between steps 1 and 2 that only displayed text to confirm that nothing had errored at that point. When the flow errored out with this extra screen, the extra screen was blamed for the conversion error despite the fact that it was neither taking any input nor assigning anything.

The approval process called by the flow has no entry criteria, it fails with users that meet the 'Initial Submitters' criteria, and the only initial action is to lock the record.

At this point I've hit a wall in trying to figure out where else to look, any help would be appreciated.